# How to add a header named "Cookie" with HttpClient?

Tags: httpclient, asp.net-web-api

An API that i use, force me to use the authentication token in a header named "Cookie".

i try the following code using WebApiClient:

```
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", _token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync("myapi").Result;
```

But the request goes without "Cookie" header. Removes itself. When i change the header name "CookieX" or whatever else it is shown in the request.

is there any way to insert a header named "Cookie"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved using ClientHandler's **UseCookie** property.

```
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.UseCookies = false;

        _client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```